# Как создать элемент по клику в таблице?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Новичок в реакте, понимаю в теории, но не могу сделать это на практике, как можно добавить элемент по клику в таблицу с 3-мя полями по инпуту?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
// import Header from './components/Header';
// import Table from './components/Table';

function App() {
  
    let data = [
      {id: "1", firstName: "Иван", lastName:"Иванов", position:'Менеджер'},
      {id: "2", firstName: "Пётр", lastName:"Петров", position:'Сисадмин'},
      {id: "3", firstName: "Сара", lastName:"Конор", position:'Бухгалтер'},
      {id: "4", firstName: "Фёдор", lastName:"Федоров", position:'Архитектор'},
      {id: "5", firstName: "Алексей", lastName:"Алексеев", position:'Оператор'},
      {id: "6", firstName: "Марина", lastName:"Маринина", position:'Менеджер'},
      {id: "7", firstName: "Михаил", lastName:"Михайлов", position:'Директор'},
      {id: "8", firstName: "Валентина", lastName:"Иванова", position:'Художник'}
    ];
  
  let tempValue = { id: "9", firstName: "Ив", lastName: "Ивано", position: 'Менеджер' };

  const editStyle = {
    marginLeft: '10px',
  };

  const [newList,updateData] = useState(data);

  function deleteElement(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    updateData((tempState)=>{
      let listItems = [];
      tempState.forEach(element => {
        if(element.id !==e.target.attributes[2].value){
          listItems.push(element)
        }
      })
      return listItems
    })
  }
  
  function addElement(e) {
    updateData((tempState) => {
        var listItems = [];
        tempState.forEach(element => {
            listItems.push(element)
        })
        listItems.push(tempValue)
        return listItems
    })
  }

  // function changeEdit(props){
  //   return (<button type = "button" className="btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>)
  // }

  function ListTable(props) {
      var listItems = [];
      newList.forEach(element => {
          listItems.push(
              <tr key={element.id}>
                  <td><input type="text" readOnly value={element.id} /></td>
                  <td><input type="text" readOnly value={element.firstName} /></td>
                  <td><input type="text" readOnly value={element.lastName} /></td>
                  <td><input type="text" readOnly value={element.position} /></td>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-outline-danger"
                      number={element.id}
                      onClick={deleteElement}>
                      Delete
                    </button>
                    <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-outline-success"                    
                    style={editStyle}>                                        
                    Edit
                    </button>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          );
      });
    return (listItems)
  }
  
  return (
      <div className='table' >
      <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-outline-success"
      onClick={addElement}>    
      Add User
      </button>
      <thead className="thead-dark">
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <ListTable/>
      </tbody>
  </div>    
  )
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addElement(e) {
    updateData([...newList.map(elem => ({...elem})),{...tempValue}])
  }
```

Comment: А как бы я мог добавить объект, который бы считывался с инпутов?

Comment: @ДамирМухомедзянов событие на submit -> обект в аргументы -> и тоже что с верху
на счет формы поиши react forms , react hook forms ... поможет только надо разобратся